# Wordpress add_action and mysql_select_db not saving

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When I add mysql_select_db("table", $con); to the code, I am not able to save the post.

When I click on save the system message says "post saved" but nothing changes. 
If I try and create a new post I get "Submit for review" instead of "Publish".

if I type in a fake table everything works for example mysql_select_db("fake_table", $con);

Here is the code

```
add_action('save_post', 'export_to_ci');
function export_to_ci($post_id) {
//Connect to Database
$con =  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("table", $con);
```

Comment: You can't do it they way you are doing it, you need to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: It doesn't tell me anything about connecting and saving to another database

Comment: @user742736 I don't get what you mean when you say "nothing changes".

Answer (score 0):

@user742736 The link @SMacFayden gives you (see comments) is the proper way for beginning. There you have the basics regarding to db operations on WordPress.

First of all you shouldn't use your own `mysql_connect` since WordPress provides a class of functions called `wpdb` for all database manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I used.

```
add_action('save_post', 'export_to_ci');

function export_to_ci($post_id) {
//verify post is not a revision
if (!wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {

//Connect to CI Database
$ci_db = new wpdb("root", "root", "db_name", "localhost");
$ci_db->show_errors();

$results = $ci_db->get_results("SELECT * FROM blog_post");

}
```